# Trying to replace <br>, <BR>, <br +attribute> tags with <br/>

Tags: java, regex

I am attempting to convert a bunch of HTML documents to XML compliance (via a java method) and there are a lot of `<br>` tags that either (1) are unclosed or (2) contain attributes.  For some reason the regex I'm using does not address the tags that contain attributes.  Here is the code:

```
htmlString = htmlString.replaceAll("(?i)<br *>", "<br/>");
```

This code works fine for all the `<br>` tags in the documents; it replaces them with `<br/>`.  However, for tags like

```
<BR style="PAGE-BREAK-BEFORE: always" clear=all>
```

it doesn't do anything.  I'd like all br tags to just be `<br/>`, regardless of any attributes in the tag prior to conversion.

What do I need to add to my regex in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will do what you want:  `<(BR|br)[^>]*>`

Here is a working example:  [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/47n1lY/1)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want `<br\b[^>]*>` to match all tags that

- Start with `<br`
- Have a word-break after the `<br` (so you wouldn't match a `<brown>` tag, for example
- Contain any number of non-`>` characters, including 0
- End with a `>`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.*` instead of `*` :

```
htmlString.replaceAll("(?i)<br .*>", "<br/>")
//-----------------------------^^
```

because :

> `*` Match the preceding character or subexpression 0 or more times.

and

> `.*` Matches any character zero or many times

So for your case :

```
String htmlString = "<BR style=\"PAGE-BREAK-BEFORE: always\" clear=all>";
System.out.println(htmlString.replaceAll("(?i)<br .*>", "<br/>"));
```

**Output**

```
<br/>
```

Comment: `.*` is not a good idea.  What will that pattern do with `<br ><strong>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</strong>`?

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions to parse HTML is not a good idea because HTML is not regular. You should use a proper parsing library like [NekoHTML](http://nekohtml.sourceforge.net/).

> NekoHTML is a simple HTML scanner and tag balancer that enables
>   application programmers to parse HTML documents and access the
>   information using standard XML interfaces. The parser can scan HTML
>   files and "fix up" many common mistakes that human (and computer)
>   authors make in writing HTML documents. NekoHTML adds missing parent
>   elements; automatically closes elements with optional end tags; and
>   can handle mismatched inline element tags.